Python3 cryptography. Создание самоподписанного корневого сертификата
пытаюсь разобраться с задачей создания локального центра сертификации на python cryptography.
При использовании openssl есть опция -config, где указывается файл конфигурации openssl и другие опции.
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout /srv/хххххх/ca.key -out /srv/хххххх/private/ca.pem \
        -days 365 -config /srv/хххххх/config/ca.cnf \
        -passin pass:ХХХХХХХ -passout pass:ХХХХХХХ

Как мне создать такой же корневой сертификат при помощи cryptography?
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Если есть примеры, дайте ссылочку.

Оф дока

Я читал официальную документацию, не нашел в ней как передать параметры из конфига, поэтому и задал вопрос.

Прошу прощения, не верно понял Ваш вопрос. Функции чтения параметров из конфига нет, хотя это странно с учётом того, что cryptography базируется на openssl. Все параметрами прописывать только в коде как в доке. Можете предложить разрабам свою реализацию, возможно они включат её в репу
